# SQLite visual editor for windows

Tags: sqlite

Is there any (preferably freeware) SQLite editor that has the followiong features:

- Change the column order on the tables. (not a deal breaker if it doesnt)
- Lets me paste a set data from an excel table, like entire columns/rows. (this is what i really need)

I'm using SQlite Browser and it's very good but I have to add a lot of data which I have stored in an Excel spreadsheet. Sqlite browser only lets me edit a single cell at a time, which is very time consuming as you can imagine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out SQLite Maestro does both things. It's not free though, but has a 30day trial.

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLite Manager](http://sqlite-manager.googlecode.com/) plugin for Firefox allows you to import data from CSV, and is freeware. I don't think it lets you copy and paste, but you could export from Excel to CSV and then import that file. Of course, it requires Firefox, which may make it unacceptable to you.

I don't see any way to use it to reorder columns, however.